# Magento New Products Widget Pagination not working

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, widget

I am in Magento 1.9 and have added the New Products Widget to my homepage;

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" show_pager="1" products_per_page="2" products_count="10" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```

Now even though I have choosen to only show 2 products per page and to display pagination all of the products just display and there is no pagination displayed anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

This might help you, Add following code in Layout XML:

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
        <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
        </block>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
        <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: All this does is add a totally new product list for category 3 to my page! This does nothing to help with why the pager is not showing on the new products widget